# Closing realm on UI thread

Tags: android, realm

Does closing one instance of realm on the UI close all other instances on the UI. I'm getting this error in my crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm instance has been closed or this object or its parent has been deleted.
       at io.realm.RealmList.checkValidView(Unknown Source)
       at io.realm.RealmList.size(Unknown Source)
       at io.realm.RealmBaseAdapter.getCount(Unknown Source)
       at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:826)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6728)
       at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
       at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
       at io.realm.RealmBaseAdapter$1.onChange(Unknown Source)
       at io.realm.RealmBaseAdapter$1.onChange(Unknown Source)
       at io.realm.internal.Collection$RealmChangeListenerWrapper.onChange(Unknown Source)
       at io.realm.internal.Collection$CollectionObserverPair.onChange(Unknown Source)
       at io.realm.internal.Collection$Callback.onCalled(Unknown Source)
       at io.realm.internal.Collection$Callback.onCalled(Unknown Source)
       at io.realm.internal.ObserverPairList.foreach(Unknown Source)
       at io.realm.internal.Collection.notifyChangeListeners(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:328)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

what could be the cause of this error, cause I was told it occurred while switching fragments. The only occurence of `realm.close()` is in the `onDestroy()` method of the `MainActivity`.

Comment: This answer depends on where you open/close your local Realm instance for the UI thread in your fragments.

Comment: on realm instances are local to the `onCreateView()` method for fragments

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when I passed realm instance from activity to fragments. It's not good idea... Acording to the [Controlling the lifecycle of Realm instances](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances) paragraph from documentation, you need to **open own realm instance for every activity or fragment and close it independently**.

Also, I wish to note an comment for `MyFragment` sample:

> // Note that if the db is large, getting the Realm instance may, briefly, block rendering.
>   // In that case it may be preferable to manage the Realm instance and RecyclerView from
>   // onStart/onStop instead. Returning a view, immediately, from onCreateView allows the
>   // fragment frame to be rendered while the instance is initialized and the view loaded.

In my case it was very helpfull

Comment: seems the issue was not closing of the realm instance but the failure of validating realm objects in the `RealmBaseAdapter` I opened the issue here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4641